# extracting vdate form nc header with bash without opening file

Tags: bash, header, netcat

I have to change the title of a couple of hundred files by adding the vdate from its header to its title.

If **vdate = 19971222**, then I want the name of that nc file to become **rerun4_spindown_19971222.nc**

I know I can find the vdate by `ncdump -h filename` (see example header below).

```
ncdump -h rerun4_1997_spindown_09191414_co2 
netcdf rerun4_1997_spindown_09191414_co2 {
dimensions:
    lon = 768 ;
    lat = 384 ;
    nhgl = 192 ;
    nlevp1 = 96 ;
    spc = 32896 ;

// global attributes:
        :file_type = "Restart history file" ;
        :source_type = "IEEE" ;
        :history = "" ;
        :user = " Linda" ;
        :created = " Date - 20190919 Time - 134447" ;
        :label_1 = " Atmospheric model " ;
        :label_2 = " Library 23-Feb-2012" ;
        :label_3 = " Lin & Rood ADVECTION is default" ;
        :label_4 = " Modified physics" ;
        :label_5 = " Modified radiation" ;
        :label_6 = " Date - 20190919 Time - 134447" ;
        :label_7 = " Linda " ;
        :label_8 = " Linux " ;
        :fdate = 19950110 ;
        :ftime = 0 ;
        :vdate = 19971222 ;
        :vtime = 235800 ;
        :nstep = 776158 ;
        :timestep = 120. ;
```

However, then I have to manually open all the files and manually change the title of the file... of hundreds of files. I would prefer making a bash that can automatically do that.

I am sure there must be a more intelligent way to extract the vdate from the nc header, could you guys help me out?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post sample input and output ? In particular, is 'header' the first line of the input file ? Also, you refer to the 'title' of the file - do you mean the file name ? Do you have some code that you have already tried ?

Comment: @dash-o I have altered the text with an example of the header. This is the 'hidden' information a nc file contains and not part of the data that you read out. I ahve tried ```ncdump -h -vdate filename``` but that didn't work. I know that people use ```ncatted -O -a vdate,global,o,l,<newdate> <filename>``` to change the original vdate. I am not sure how I can use that to just extract it and use it for the file name.

Comment: Can you clarify what is the common pattern to ALL input files - e.g. is it rerun4_spindown_NNNNNNN.nc, where NNNNNNNN is to be modified, or something else.

Comment: @dash-o Exactly like that. All input files have this 'rerun4_spindown_NNNNNN.,nc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, something like that should work:

```
#! /bin/sh
for file in rerun4_*_spindown_* ; do

  vdate=$(ncdump -h $file | awk '$1 == ":vdate" { print $3 }')
  new_name="rerun4_spindown_$vdate.nc"
  mv "$file" "$new_name"
done
```

I do not have access to netCDF files - more testing is needed.

Comment: That works! great! It however doesn't understand the extglob command, but that doesn't seem to bother the functioning of this code. Thanks you very much!

Comment: @Linda - extglob is leftover from another script. You can ignore it.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.